# Can I update the GraphQL Schema?

Tags: graphql

````
```app.use("/graphql", expressGraphQL({
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true,
}))```
````

I am developing a Quick schema builder, therefore, I hope the schema can be edited.
I declared the schema as a variable, I added some functionality to update the schema.
However, no matter what the new stuff I added, the path (./graphql) wont read it. just remember the first schema.

is there any way to do the same thing?

Comment: How are you updating the schema?

Can you provide additional code around that?

Comment: I created a textarea in frontEnd, and will send the post request to backend, and then, it will become a newScheme

Comment: In my project, there are 2 pages, one is home page with textarea, which allows users edit the Schema, and there is a button to send the post request to server, server will recieve the new Schema and redirect the page to the second page( graphQL playgrond)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: OP was asking about hot reload of a schema**

This is discussed here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1275#issuecomment-513364165

- [Solution 1](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1275#issuecomment-445382220)
- [Solution 2](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1275#issuecomment-513364165)
- [Solution 3](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1275#issuecomment-526591251)
- [Solution 4](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1275#issuecomment-530375244)
- [Solution 5](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1275#issuecomment-532183702)

---

Old Answer

Making the assumption that `schema` is the response from `buildSchema`.
`schema` cannot be updated directly via adding additional `SDL` text without first calling [printSchema()](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printschema), passing in `schema`, which returns an SDL representation of the schema.

```js
const sdlSchema = printSchema(schema);
sdlSchema +=`
type Book {
  title: string
  color: string
}
`
const newBuiltSchema = buildSchema(sdlSchema);
app.use("/graphql", expressGraphQL({
  schema: newBuiltSchema,
  graphiql: true,
}))
```

This `SDL` schema may be updated by appending additional `SDL` compliant GraphQL definitions.

```
//ex.

type Book {
  title: string
  color: string
}

// or query or mutation
```

Comment: without reload the server, it seems that the endpoint of graphql remembered the first schema, and wont change due to schema updating

Comment: @WillLo, I have updated the original answer with a specific approach for "hot reload" of a schema.